# Windows Server 2012 Joomla installation under IIS 500.50 error when clicking on PDF link

Tags: ntfs, iis, joomla

I have a stock standard Windows Server 2012 that I used Web Platform Installer to install Joomla 3.x. I configured Joomla to doe URL rewriting and did not modify anything else (nothing in the J! web.config or in IIS) and the rewriting works without a problem when serving up HTML pages.

However when a user clicks on a link to a PDF file IIS returns a 500.50 error. So out of the "Things To Try" in the error description:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for web.config allow access

All good as otherwise regular URL rewriting would not work.

- Check event logs to see if something useful was logged

Nothing out of the ordinary.

- Verify permissions for the DLL

As other rewrites are working this is also not an issue.

- Install the .NET Extensibily feature if request is mapped to a managed handler

To my knowledge this is not applicable as this is coming via the **StaticFile** handler? (And I have checked that the PDF MIME extension is mapped)

I have also verified that the physical PDF file is on the disk where it is supposed to be and that there is appropriate NTFS permissions to access the file.

So has anyone got any suggestions on how I can track this down? As I said this is a stock standard install of Windows Server 2012 and WPI to do Joomla.

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Bump? Anyone got any suggestions?